# jquery plugin - how to select its child elements and not other instances?

Tags: jquery

I am developing a jquery plugin. I have multiple instances of the plugin. 
In the plugin I replace the instantiated element with more dom. I  use `this.parent().find(...)` to target these elements.

But this also affects elements under other instances too. How do I select the elements of that particular instance only?

code sample

```
$('#one').pluginXX();
$('#two').pluginXX();

$.fn.pluginXX = function(options){

   var wrapper = this.parent();
   this.hide(); //hide the instantiated element

   wrapper.append(/**many elements***/);

   //i use $ document because button is generated dynamically
   $(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
       wrapper.find('ul').append("<li>item</li>");
   });
```

Comment: Are you sure `this.parent()` works, since `parent()` is a jquery function?

Comment: It works but some time multiple object gets selected when there are multiple instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*`this` is the element, `$(this)` is the jQuery object constructed with that element*, so you need to use `$(this)` everywhere instead of `this` as `.hide` and `.parent()` are `jQuery` methods and applicable only upon `jQuery` objects.

```
$('#one').pluginXX();
$('#two').pluginXX();

$.fn.pluginXX = function(options){

   var wrapper = $(this).parent();
   $(this).hide(); //hide the instantiated element

   wrapper.append(/**many elements***/);

   //i use $ document because button is generated dynamically
   $(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
       wrapper.find('ul').append("<li>item</li>");
   });

}
```

To find any element inside `$(this)` simply use another method like `.find()` for ex. `$(this).find("button")`, will select all the button elements inside the current element.

To set a event handler like click on it's children element say button cab be done using

```
$(this).on('click', 'button', function(){
    wrapper.find('ul').append("<li>item</li>");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `$(this).parent()` instead of `this.parent()` and `$(this).hide()` instead of `this.hide()` because `this` is not `jQuery` object. Try like following. Hope this will help you.

```
$('#one').pluginXX();
$('#two').pluginXX();

$.fn.pluginXX = function(options){

    var wrapper = $(this).parent();
    $(this).hide(); //hide the instantiated element

    wrapper.append(/**many elements***/);

    $(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
       wrapper.find('>ul').append("<li>item</li>");
    });
}
```

Comment: `this` returns error when i call inside `$(document).on('click')`

Comment: `$('this')` will be the object i click. Its tedious to select the elements from the button to parents and then to children.

Comment: I've updated my answer once again. Hope this helps. @AbelD